# primeng accordion header button

Tags: accordion, primeng

I have Angular 5 application and I am using PrimeNG components. I created the PrimeNG accordion with defined header where are the title and some action buttons, like this:

```
<p-accordion>
   <p-accordionTab>
      <p-header>
         <span>Some card title</span>
         <p-button title="Delete" (onClick)="deleteCard()"></p-button>
      </p-header>
   </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

Issue is that when I click on the button inside accordion header, the particular accordionTab fire toggle open/close click event, which looks very weird. How I can separate these two clicks?

Thanks for advice.

Comment: Are you looking to stop the toggle open / close event

Comment: yes, I want to just stop toggle open/close when you click on the button which is located in header

Comment: Pls post the primeng version

Answer (score 15):

I know this is an old post, but I'm posting for anyone that comes across this like I did.

In the click method of the button, add `$event.stopPropagation();` followed by your own event, such as `deleteCard()` like in OPs post.

```
<p-accordion>
   <p-accordionTab>
      <p-header>
         <span>Some card title</span>
         <p-button title="Delete" (onClick)="$event.stopPropagation(); deleteCard()"></p-button>
      </p-header>
   </p-accordionTab>
</p-
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I wanted to add a button to the accordion but when clicking it the event that would open the accordion would not be executed, and browsing through other similar questions I found myself creating a directive

```
/* DIRECTIVE */

import {Directive, HostListener} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[stop-propagation]"
})
export class mymodule {

    @HostListener("click", ["$event"])
    public onClick(event: any): void
    {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

---

```
 /* HTML */
   <p-accordion>
   <p-accordionTab>
      <p-header>
         <span>Some card title</span>
         <p-button title="Delete" stop-propagation (onClick)="deleteCard()"></p-button>
      </p-header>
   </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```